# Find solution of complex multiplication of gamma distributions.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, gamma-distribution

As my main goal is to find the path, or change in $\theta$ value as $k$ changes.
So I am trying to find the solution value for $\theta$.

The equation that I want to solve is :

given two gamma distributions $f_{1}(x), f_2(x)$, and $k$ is a constant,

$f_1(\theta)\left(2\int_{0}^{\theta}f_1(x)\mathrm dx -1\right) = kf_2(\theta)\left(2\int_{0}^{\theta}f_2(x)\mathrm dx -1\right)$

I thought about solving with Laplace transformation, but it will have convolution terms and get too complex.
Do you have any thoughts or is this even feasible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't lower bounds on integrals start at zero?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes, Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Are you using shape-scale, i.e. $(k,\theta)$, parameterization for your gamma distributions? Do f1 and f2 have different parameters?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson, I am using different $\alpha, \beta$ for gamma distribution.
$\theta$ is just a variable that I would like to find the value.